# Custom Model Fields Binding Values

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i hasclass named TField, i used this class as field for all model fields.

**TField Class :**

```
namespace MvcBase.Core
{
    public class TField : TBaseField
    {
        public TField( string iName ):base(null,iName, TFieldType.ftText , iName) { 

        }
        public TField(TBaseModel iModel, string iName, TFieldType iType, string iDisplayName):base(iModel, iName, iType, iDisplayName)
        {

        } //end constructor 



    } //end class
} //end namespace
```

Now in my custom model i defined my form model inputs like this

```
    public class TModel_Login_User : TBaseModel
    {

        public TField Username { get; set; }
        public TField Password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**The Problem Is Posting Form To My Custom Model .**

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Login( TModel_Login_User user) {



    return View("Index");
}
```

All fields are comes nulls, i know is somewhere must define something to place form values in TField value property.

Any help

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your html form?

Comment: my html form it's so simple  just two html inputs with names, Username and  Password .... for your know when I change model fields from TField to String the post comes Ok.